# Sort X and Y co-ordinates using Ramda

Tags: javascript, sorting, ramda.js

I have an array of the form:

```
[
  { i: 'text', layout: {x: 1, y: 0} }
  { i: 'text', layout: {x: 0, y: 0} }
  { i: 'text', layout: {x: 1, y: 1} }
]
```

I would like to sort the array using ramda package

I have reached so far as to sorting Y first --

```
const sortedY = R.sortBy(R.path(['layout', 'y']));
const temp = sortedY(originalContent);
```

Please suggest how I can sort x and y -

```
{x: 0, y: 0}
{x: 1, y: 0}
{x: 1, y: 1}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sortWith](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortWith) to sort using multiple comparators.

```
const xySort = R.sortWith([
  R.ascend(R.path(['layout','x'])),
  R.ascend(R.path(['layout','y']))
])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use [sortWith](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#sortWith).

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/Bronzdragon/nxwv40uz/5/):

```
var list = [
  { i: 'first', layout: {x: 1, y: 1} },
  { i: 'second', layout: {x: 1, y: 0} },
  { i: 'third', layout: {x: 0, y: 1} },
];

var xySort = R.sortWith([
  R.ascend(R.path(['layout', 'x'])),
  R.ascend(R.path(['layout', 'y'])),
]);

console.log(xySort(list));
```